# How do I install iwconfig without yum?

Tags: centos, terminal, wifi

I am using [this tutorial](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/WpaSupplicant) to try to set up wireless on a new CentOS 7 installation that is not connected to the internet.  However, when I type `iwconfig` into the terminal, it replies with `-bash: iwconfig: command not found`.

I cannot type `yum install iwconfig` because this machine is not connected to the internet.  Instead, I have to download rpm files to another machine and then transfer them manually to the new CentOS 7 development server.  So I started by downloading the rpm file [from this link](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=iwconfig&submit=Search+...&system=centos&arch=x86_64) and moving it to the development server.  Then I continued to try to install the rpm files until I resolved each of the errors by downloading and installing dependency rpm files using the same method.  Finally, when all the dependencies seemed to be installed, I got the following `ls -al` results, but yet I am still getting the `-bash: iwconfig: command not found` error, as you can see below:

```
[root@localhost wpa_supplicant_rpm_files]# ls -al
total 1128
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   4096 Sep 16 17:24 .
dr-xr-x---. 3 root root   4096 Sep 15 13:25 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  30064 Sep 16 17:20 crda-1.1.3_2014.06.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  61048 Sep 16 17:22 iw-3.10-6.el7.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 131032 Sep 16 17:24 libnl-1.1.4-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  95724 Sep 16 17:18 wireless-tools-29-6.el6.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 820636 Sep 16 10:05 wpa_supplicant-2.0-13.el7_0.x86_64.rpm
[root@localhost wpa_supplicant_rpm_files]# rpm -Uvh *rpm
warning: crda-1.1.3_2014.06.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
warning: wireless-tools-29-6.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
    package wpa_supplicant-1:2.0-13.el7_0.x86_64 is already installed
[root@localhost wpa_supplicant_rpm_files]# iwconfig
-bash: iwconfig: command not found
[root@localhost wpa_supplicant_rpm_files]#
```

**So how do I get the `iwconfig` command to work without `yum`?**

Note that the process is to download to a devbox, which then uses `scp` to transfer to the development server through an ethernet cable which is the only connection that the development server has to any other computer.

Comment: If the package installed correctly, then it likely placed the `iwconfig` binary somewhere other than your normal path. Run `rpm -ql wireless-tools` to get a list of files which the package installed and see if `iwconfig` is in there. If so, try to run it from its absolute path.

Comment: @alienth Seems that `wireless-tools` are not installed.  Please see result that I added to the end of my OP just now.

Comment: @don_crissti Perhaps, but typing `iw` also results in `iw
-bash: iw: command not found`, even though I seem to have downloaded the `rpm` for `iw`, so the underlying cause might be the same.  Here is the download link, which you can cross check with the OP: http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=iw&submit=Search+...&system=centos&arch=x86_64

Comment: @don_crissti It was, but it is still available on EL7/cent7.

Comment: @CodeMed This question and [How do I configure wlp3s0 wireless connection in CentOS 7?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230184/how-do-i-configure-wlp3s0-wireless-connection-in-centos-7) are related.  Please do not post new questions on related topics until this one or the other on is marked Answered/Closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the packages are just not installing because they aren't signed with a key that your system recognizes, which is to be expected from random packages downloaded from non-official repos. You have another problem in that you're installing mixed el6 and el7 packages.

To install `wireless-tools`, without using yum:

Download the `epel-release` package from the fedora project and install that (provided it isn't already installed). That will setup the needed GPG keys.

https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

Download the `wireless-tools` package from the EPEL repository, which can be found here:

https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repoview/wireless-tools.html

That package should install properly after the `epel-release` package has been installed.

If you also need the `crda` package, it can be found in Centos' main repo:

http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7/os/x86_64/Packages/crda-1.1.3_2014.06.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

Additional dependencies:

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/iw-3.10-6.el7.x86_64.rpm
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/libnl-1.1.4-3.el7.x86_64.rpm

All of these packages can be installed via `rpm -Uvh`. Note that if `rpm` spits back any type of error for any one package, such as `already installed`, it will not perform actions on any of the other packages you asked to install.

Comment: That did not resolve the problem.  I followed your instructions explicitly, and posted the logs at the end of my OP above, but I am still getting the `NOKEY` error, and there are also still additional dependencies to add.

Comment: Looks like things are installing properly (epel-release did, at least). You just need to follow the dependency tree from here. The NOKEY warning can safely be ignored.

Comment: @CodeMed The iw package can be found here: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/iw-3.10-6.el7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Then where do I get the dependencies?  You did not like the source I posted before.

Comment: I'd recommend always using the official Centos repos, or Fedora's EPEL repo. Those will have everything you need to get `wireless-tools` installed. There is no easy way to search those repos online. You'll just have to navigate through the http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7 directories to find what you're looking for.

Comment: `libnl.so.1()(64bit)` does not show up at that link.  And it is next on the tree after `iw`.

Comment: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/libnl-1.1.4-3.el7.x86_64.rpm

The `Packages` page is very long, so be sure your browser has fully loaded it before searching.

Comment: I followed the chain to its completion, but I am still getting the same error.  So the problem is not yet resolved.  I posted the logs at the end of my OP.  Care to take a look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29212/discussion-between-alienth-and-codemed).